# How can I clear a string from a Java program's memory?

Tags: java, jvm

I'm trying to learn JVM attaching. I've learned how to attach the agent to the JVM, and it all works fine. My question is, is it possible to remove the string from the target's memory after attaching? If you search for the .jar using Process Hacker 2, you can find its path in the memory. Example:
[image: In this screenshot there are alot of strings left in the memory]

I've seen programs doing similar things, like LSquad (which is a program for clearing Minecraft hacks' strings). I tried decompiling it using Luyten, and I saw it uses an external DLL. Can you do it in native java, or there is an external library required?

Comment: You can remove a String by not referring to that String any more (and performing a GC, most likely needing a full GC)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: but how can you know that it has also been removed/gc'd from the String pool?

Comment: Will performing a System.gc() in the agent help?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels do a heap dump and look for the String.

Comment: Use char arrays for sensitive data instead.

Comment: @TsvetomirBonev only after it is no longer used anywhere (via a strong reference)

Comment: The mutable `char[]` or `byte[]` or `StringBuilder` or `ByteBuffer` or `CharBuffer` are good alternatives. Worst case, you can overwrite the String's underlying array. The encryption libraries use byte[] or ByteBuffer.

Comment: I never actually use those strings in my code, they get created automatically when attaching, this is just how java works.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove a String or any object by not referring to that String any more (and performing a GC, most likely needing a full GC)

In your case, the String highlighted is for a jar and most likely you need to unload that DLL to free it up. (I don't know if, or how you would do that in a JVM)

Comment: It's actually not a .dll file, it's just a .jar file which contains a Main class and Agent class. The agent class gets loaded in the JVM by creating a new VirtualMachine, which is attached to the target, which after successful loading gets detached. I don't know how to unload that class though

Comment: @TsvetomirBonev To unload a class, you need to unload the ClassLoader which loaded it (and all references to any instance loaded by that ClassLoader)

Comment: Can you show me an example? I am not that experienced in Java (it's probably obvious)

Comment: @TsvetomirBonev most likely, there is a simpler way to do what you are trying to achieve.  e.g. the simplest way to unload a class is to restart the JVM.

Comment: I've seen other people doing something similar, the actual program doesn't close but it kind of reloads, I may try to look up how to do that.

Comment: @TsvetomirBonev Using a ClassLoader is an advanced topic, of the container which do this, I would say it took 5-10 years for them to have a good implementation.

Comment: @TsvetomirBonev a JVM can start another JVM feeding it inputs before closing. This trip is useful if you need to change the heap size for example.

Comment: @TsvetomirBonev I suggest reading these answers https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=classloader+unloading&oq=classloader+unloading&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.5486j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @TsvetomirBonev my instructions are an incredible simplification of what you would need to do in reality so if what I have said is not immediately obvious, the actual implementation will be 100x harder.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help, I am still learning java and it's hard for me to understand, but I will look through the link you gave

Comment: @TsvetomirBonev some things are harder, and some things whole teams of experts who specialise in something struggle to get right over a decade, and unloading a ClassLoader is one of them, but there is no other way to unload a String which is associated with a class or jar loaded by a classloader.

Comment: @Tsvetomir Bonev: When you are “still learning java”, writing Java Agents surely isn’t the best starting point.